# In python, how can I pass parameter as an object, not variables and combine them

Tags: python-2.7

I have defined a class called food whose parameters are calorie, sodium, potassium, carbs, fiber, sugar, protein, va, vc, calcium, and iron. Then I can create food in this class, such as English cucumber, crab stick, sea weed, and brown rice. I want to have an either user defined function or a method in food class that allows me to combine those food together to create a new food called California roll, and it calculates all the attributes of this new food.

```
class Food:
def __init__(self, name, cal, fat, sod, pot, carbs, fiber, sugar, protein, va, vc, calcium, iron, unit):
    self.name = name
    self.cal = cal
    self.fat = fat
    self.sod = sod
    self.pot = pot
    self.carbs = carbs
    self.fiber = fiber
    self.sugar = sugar
    self.protein = protein
    self.va = va
    self.vc = vc
    self.calcium = calcium
    self.iron = iron

englishcucumber = Food('English Cucumber', 15, 0, 2, 147, 2, 0.5, 1.7, 0.7, 2, 5, 2, 2,1)
brownrice = Food("Brown Rice", 1440, 12, 80, 0, 312, 16, 8, 32, 0, 0, 0, 10, 4)
crabstick = Food("Crab Stick", 33, 0, 116.7, 0, 4.7, 1.3, 0, 4, 0, 0.33, 0.33, 0, 2)
seawead = Food("Sea Wead", 10, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 6, 4, 0, 3, 1)
```

I have already defined an object, how can I combine those objects? Is there any ways I can define a function whose input variables are objects not just normal variables?

Comment: Could you please fix the title of your question so that it is clear what your are asking for BY TITLE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, name, cal, fat, sod, pot, carbs, fiber, sugar, protein, va, vc, calcium, iron, unit):
        self.name = name
        self.cal = cal
        self.fat = fat
        self.sod = sod
        self.pot = pot
        self.carbs = carbs
        self.fiber = fiber
        self.sugar = sugar
        self.protein = protein
        self.va = va
        self.vc = vc
        self.calcium = calcium
        self.iron = iron

    def combine(self, name, other):
        """Given a name and another class instance of food, return a food instance with all of the values combined."""
        r = Food(name, cal=self.cal+other.cal, fat=self.fat+other.fat, sod=self.sod+other.sod, pot=self.pot+other.pot, carbs=self.carbs+other.carbs, fiber=self.fiber+other.fiber, sugar=self.sugar+other.sugar, protein=self.protein+other.protein, va=self.va+other.va, vc=self.vc+other.vc, calcium=self.calcium+other.calcium, iron=self.iron+other.iron, unit=self.unit+other.unit)
        return r
```

Comment: Just so you know though, you have an extra unit argument that you aren't using and aren't saving, so that will cause a bug unless you add ```self.unit = unit```. You can also use keywords to make the code more clear. Instead of just listing the numbers, try like, ```f = Food(name="chocolate", sugar=100, protein=0 ...)```.